# I want to create a new file for each iteration using for-each loop

Tags: java

I need to write a code in which i want to create each file for every iteration of a loop add data into the file. also the filename should change every time.
for example: family1_parts.txt for 1 iteration for second
family2_parts.txt for 2 iteration and so on.. using for-each loop for iteration.

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to hire a developer? If not, it would be good to show an attempt at solving the problem yourself.

Comment: Not a proper question for the SO. You should try, and if you find yourself stuck, come to find help

Comment: Start with for loop and `File file = new File(i + ".txt")` and come back when you have at least some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    String someData = "data for the files";
    FileOutputStrem fos = new FileOutputStrem(ROOT_DIR + "familyname" + n + "_parts.txt");
    fos.write(someData);
    fos.close();
}
```

`n` -> number of files or iterations you want

`someData` -> data you want in the file, simply anything

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey..thanks for your reply. I just edited the question. I would be grateful if u can suggest a little more